# PushPlugin Not Asking for Permissions on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on setting up Push Notifications for an iOS app using the Ionic Framework but I'm running into a problem.

I added the plugin using the following

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

and then added the following to my services.js file:

```
window.onNotificationAPN = function(event){
    alert(event);
}


angular.module('starter.services', [])
.run(function($ionicPlatform){
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function($scope, $window){
        var tokenHandler = function(result){
            alert('tokenHandler' + result);
        }

        var errorHandler = function(error){
            alert('errohandler' + error);
        }

        var pushNot = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        pushNot.register(
            tokenHandler,
            errorHandler,
            {
                 "badge":"true",
                 "sound":"true",
                 "alert":"true",
                 "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
            }
        );
    });
})
```

When I run the app on my test device (running iOS 6.1.6) using command+R or sending it using testflight the application runs but never asks for permission to send push notifications and the the tokenHandler function is never called.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the console log ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I was able to solve this was to switch over to using [ngCordova's Push](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Push) script with the PushPlugin.

Comment: doesnt work for me, nor doesnt compile.  ngCordova Push is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question. I was searching for this for hours.

Turns out the solution for me was making sure that the opening angular module line in the ***app.js*** file included the **ionic.service.core** module dependency.

Then everything worked.

*NOTE: (i wish it had thrown an error instead of allowing the push.register call to actually return a token)*

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.service.core'])
```